# Getting hour and minute out of a numpy array that encodes time

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a large numpy array that encodes time. Let say we have something like this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
t = {'time': ['08:35', '08:38', '13:42', '13:46']}
df = DataFrame(t)

import numpy as np
time_array = np.array(df.time)
print time_array
```

output:

```
['08:35' '08:38' '13:42' '13:46']
```

Is there an efficient way to get the hours and minutes individually from time_array?

Of course this can be done within a loop:

```
for i in range(len(time_array)):
    print np.fromstring(time_array[i], dtype=int, sep=":")
```

output:

```
[ 8 35]
[ 8 38]
[13 42]
[13 46]
```

But I am looking for a 'faster' vectorized way, if there is any.

**Edit:**

I have timed the solutions (see code below).

```
def foo(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        array[i] = np.fromstring(array[i], dtype=int, sep=':')

%timeit foo(time_array)
```

Output: 1 loops, best of 3: 3.02 s per loop

Paul H's solution 1:

```
def foo2(df):
    df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
    df['minute'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[1]))

%timeit foo2(df)
```

Output: 1 loops, best of 3: 4.31 s per loop

Paul H's solution 2:

```
import time
def foo3(df):
    df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: time.strptime(x, '%H:%M').tm_hour)
    df['minute'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: time.strptime(x, '%H:%M').tm_min)

%timeit foo3(df)
```

Output: 1 loops, best of 3: 42.1 s per loop

Answer (score 2):

I'd stay in pandas for just a little longer:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
t = {'time': ['08:35', '08:38', '13:42', '13:46']}
df = DataFrame(t)
df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
df['minute'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(':')[1]))
print(df)

    time  hour  minute
0  08:35     8      35
1  08:38     8      38
2  13:42    13      42
3  13:46    13      46
```

Then you can do `df['hour'].values` to get an array of hours.

#### Edit:

Just for grins, you could also do:

```
import time
df['hour'] = df.timestring.apply(lambda x: time.strptime(x, '%H:%M').tm_hour)
df['minute'] = df.timestring.apply(lambda x: time.strptime(x, '%H:%M').tm_min)
```